# Appliction of derivative, maximization

Tags: calculus

The problem is:

An airline will fill 100 seats of its aircraft at a fare of 200 dollars. For every 5 dollar increase in the fare, the plane loses two passengers. For every decrease of $5, the company gains two passengers. What price maximizes revenue?

I'm a bit lost as to what my equations should be. The total revenue, if all seats are filled can be 20000. So for every 5 dollar increase the total revenue becomes: $20000 - 400x$ (400x = 2 people time the price of each ticket times the number of 5 dollar increases). I don't know how to model the other situation of a 5 dollar decrease.

Comment: The five dollar increase and decrease describe the exact same behavior - that is, the information in the problem is duplicated.

Comment: Not really. It gives the information which function values apply for different intervals.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** The first part of solving such a problem is to make some definitions. Without definitions for a word-problem one doesn't get anywhere.

1. The amount of dollars a ticket costs is $x$
2. The number of passengers will be a function, let us call it $f(x)$
3. The total revenue will be a function, let us call it $g(x)$

Now you can start tying to figure out the relations between these. And once you have found $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that's when you can use your knowledge of the derivative and how you can use it.

Comment: for the minimum situation, the number of passengers can be defined as $100 - 2y$ where y is the number of 5 dollar increases. But how can I define the number of passengers in the maximum scenario? Isn't the plane bounded to carrying 100 passengers total ? Maybe I can say $100 = 2y + something$ ??

Comment: I can't see there is a maximum capacity specified in the question. Yes you could have the variable $y$ mean number of 5 dollar increases and then find an expression relating $x$ and $y$. The important part in solving a problem which is confusing and full of words is to be systematic in setting up algebraic symbols for everything. Then once you have those symbols ready you can start finding relations between them. If you start trying to solve a problem you have not even specified, you are more likely to be confused and not find a way ahead.